# Can't add snippet to VS 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, code-snippets

I'm trying to add a simple Snippet to Visual Studio 2015. I've been using the file since VS2010 so it works :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
    <Title>Custom Try Catch</Title>
    <Author>Me</Author>
    <Description>My custom try catch</Description>
    <Shortcut>tre</Shortcut>
</Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Code Language="csharp">
            <![CDATA[try
            {

            }
            catch (Exception erreur)
            {
                Utils.ManageException(erreur, this.GetType() + " > " + MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod());
            }]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

I've just installed VS2015 and tried to add it again but when I click on Code Snippets Manager under Tools I can't choose Visual C# in the language list. My project is in C# and everything is working fine (default c# snippets too).

If I click on "Import" VS doesn't give me any error but the snippet isn't working when I try.

How could I resolve this ? I guess the problem is that I can't choose Visual C# in the list.